# Computing area of very large feature collection in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, large-datasets, feature-collection

I'm trying to calculate the total area of a very large Feature Collection (over 1 million features) of burned areas over the Amazon. I want to find the total area (sum), and also the area grouped by land cover type. I'm using MapBiomas Version 6 for land cover. I have tried several ways to do this for a small number of the features, but when applied over the entire collection, it times out every time. Even when filtering for the fires over one state (there are 9 states I need to cover), the calculation times out.

1. Is there a more efficient way to tackle this problem to avoid timing out?
2. Is it possible to do this in GEE without splitting up the Feature Collection into many even smaller small chunks? (I know I could do this in ArcGIS, but I want to keep my workflow in GEE as much as possible.)

My code is as follows:

```
///////////////////////////////////
// Set up ROI and Land Cover //////
///////////////////////////////////

// The ROIs: Amazonia (amz) is the desired ROI and Mato Grosso state (MT) is a subset
var MT_filter = ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', ['Mato Grosso']);
var MT = ee.FeatureCollection(Brazil.filter(MT_filter));

Map.addLayer(MT, {color: '808080'}, 'Mato Grosso', false);
Map.addLayer(amz, {color: '808080'}, 'amz', false);

// The Land Cover data (MapBiomas)
var landcover_2020 = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_integration_v1')
.select('classification_2020').clip(amz);

//Add Burned Area polygons.
Map.addLayer(atlas_2020, {color: 'f04020'}, 'atlas fires 2020', false); // Color: red

//Clip landcover by burned areas and add to map.
var intersect = landcover_2020.clip(atlas_2020).clip(MT);

Map.addLayer(intersect, {color: 'f04020'}, 'LC Intersect', false); // Color: red


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Try to calculate Total 2020 burned area using 2 methods//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var ha = 10000; // square meters to ha conversion
var km = 1000000; // square meters to ha conversion


var MT_fires = atlas_2020.filterBounds(MT);
var test = atlas_2020.first().geometry();

// Method 1: Apply reducer to Feature Collection
// First, test over 1 feature
var img = ee.Image.pixelArea().clip(test).divide(ha);
var burned_area_test = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  geometry: test, 
  scale: 30,  
  maxPixels: 1e12
});

print(burned_area_test, 'Test - first burned area');

// Now try applying to MT ROI -- this times out.
var img2 = ee.Image.pixelArea().clip(MT_fires).divide(ha);
var MT_burned = img2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  geometry: MT_fires, 
  scale: 30,  
  maxPixels: 1e12
});

print(MT_burned, "MT Burned Area, Method 1");


// Method 2: Map Reducer over feature collection
// This also times out
var get_BA = function(feature){
  var img = ee.Image.pixelArea().clip(MT_fires).divide(ha);
  var burned_area = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: MT_fires, 
    scale: 30,  
    maxPixels: 1e12
  });
  return burned_area;
};

var burned_areas = MT_fires.map(get_BA);
print(burned_areas, "MT Burned Area, Method 2");


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Try to calculate burned area by land cover type //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Try this for the MT ROI
var img = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(ha);

var lc_areas = img.addBands(intersect)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'classification_2020',
    }),
    geometry: MT_fires,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e12
  }).get('groups');
  
print(lc_areas, "MT LC Areas");


// If we want to, we can get total Burned Area by adding up the groups
var access_items = function(innerList){
  innerList = ee.Dictionary(innerList);
  var areaList = ee.Dictionary(innerList).get('sum'); // we want to access the 'sum' (area) of each group
  return areaList;
};

var areaList = ee.List(lc_areas).map(access_items);
print(areaList, 'MT LC Areas (List)');

var total_BA = areaList.reduce({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()}); // add of the 'sum's of each group
print(total_BA, "Total BA");
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example so that the error can be reproduced (e.g. provide the featureCollection)? If you export the your out put to excel you can avoid the error, often the problem is with printing server side computations to your client-side browser: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.